# DataRow lock assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, datarow

I have a huge `Parallel.For` loop. The problem is that DataRow write operations are not multithreaded so I need to lock assign statements. It's not not a problem for me except that it looks ugly when I have to lock all assignment operations. It looks like this:

```
Parallel.For(0, ds.Tables["MyTable"].Rows.Count, i =>
lock (s_lockObject)
{
    ds.Tables["MyTable"].Rows[i]["myValue1"] = myValue1;
}
//some operations

lock (s_lockObject)
{
    ds.Tables["MyTable"].Rows[i]["myValue2"] = myValue2;
}

//some operations
lock (s_lockObject)
{
    ds.Tables["MyTable"].Rows[i]["myValue3"] = myValue3;
}
});
```

Maybe there is a way to lock assignment by default, for example write some extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of duplicate code you can extract a function for assignment DataRow value. For example:

```
    public static class DataTableExtensions
    {
        public static void SetCellValue<T>(this DataTable table, int row, string col, T value)
        {
           lock (table)
           {
              table.Rows[row][col] = value;
           }
        }
    }
```